# Using OpenCV with gpu support in anaconda

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I'm using Windows with a GTX 1050.

Currently I'm working with OpenCV in object detecting using yolo model. I found it's quite slow at ~7fps. I tried to install OpenCV with GPU support but it's only run when I execute the Python script in cmd, i mean not in Anaconda.

Is there any possible way to install OpenCV with GPU support?

Comment: "but it's only run in cmd". Whwat do you mean? What did you do to install with GPU support?

Comment: sorry, i run my python script in cmd and opencv gpu works, but not in anaconda because 
of the virtual environment.

Comment: How did you install opencv with GPU support?

Comment: well, there are some tutorial on the internet. For my case, i installed it  on windows.

Comment: So you built from source yourself using cmake? In that case, you will have to set the cmake variables pointing to python to point to your virtual environment